# TreeViewer Java

Tags: java, treeview, jface

i am building a RCP Application. I am using a custom Explorer for that.
I use Treeviewer for that with a custom content and label Provider.

My problem is now, that I am not able to display the children as children of a root Object.

The setup is as follows:
I got an Object that contains all the children (in a certain Hierarchy).
I can get the children out of that Object but i cant display them like children. My content Provider only displays them as root elements.

My question is therefore, how do I hang them in as children?
The getElement Method only return an Array of Objects, I don't understand how I can decide if Objects in that Array are parents or children.

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `TreeViewer` you use a content provider which implements `ITreeContentProvider`.

The `getElements` method of `ITreeContentProvider` should only return the top level elements of the tree.

To determine if a tree element has any children the tree viewer will call the content provider `hasChildren` method:

```
public boolean hasChildren(Object element)
```

here `element` is an existing element in the tree.

To get the children of an element the tree viewer will call the `getChildren` method:

```
public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement)
```

The provider returns any children for the element `parentElement`. If there are no children return an empty array, never return `null`.

For more details see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm?PHPSESSID=4d48764999a9cb66a7fd58a954ef2131)